# Copy data from dynamically named source file into master file

Tags: excel, vba

I have a Master workbook (Consolidate Tracker) where we add data from Source file.

Consolidated Tracker and Source file have three tabs (Open Positions, Closed, Cancelled).

Every week I put data from Source file (from each tab) into the Consolidated file (to each tab).
For example: Open Positions data from Source file goes to Open Positions in Consolidated Tracker and so on.

I am facing the following issues:

1. I have to give full name of the files.
   For example. `Workbooks("Source*")` is not working.
   Is there a way to give only partial names?
   My file name will have a date in the end. Hence I want to give *.
2. `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(I)` or `ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Name")` always goes for the Open Worksheet/Tab.
3. Pasting the output gives the following error.

> Method PasteSpecial of Object Range Failed

4. `Selection.EntireRow.Delete` sometimes gives error or sometimes
   doesn’t delete and again goes into For loop.

Also, it seems the loop is not taking the next tab.

```vb
Sub GetSheets()
    Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\2018\ VBA\Consolidated Tracker.xlsm")
    Workbooks("Source_Tracker.xlsx").Activate
    For I = 1 To 3
        Set Sheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(I)
        Columns("A:A").Select
        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight
        Range("A1").Select
        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

        With Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
            .Value = Date
            .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
        End With

        Range("A1").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Copy
        Workbooks("Consolidated Tracker").Activate
        Set Sheet = Workbooks("Consolidated Tracker.xlsm").Sheets(I)
        Range("A100000").Select
        Selection.End(xlUp).Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        ActiveCell.PasteSpecial 
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Delete
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a reason that you need to create a new application instance? BTW, the necessity for the extension may be due to a File Explorer setting that involves showing the extension (aka type).

Comment: Problem 2: I really don't like working with "Active Workbook".
You could consider working with: Sheets("Sheetname").   ...

Answer (score 1):

Consider this rewrite.

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetSheets()
    Dim i As Long, lr As Long
    Dim wb1 As Workbook, wb1 As Workbook

    Application.Workbooks.Open Filename:="D:\2018\ VBA\Consolidated Tracker.xlsm", _
                               ReadOnly:=True, AddToMru:=False

    setWbs wb1, wb2

    With wb1
        For i = 1 To 3
            With .Worksheets(i)
                .Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
                lr = Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1), _
                                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                With .Range(.Cells(1, "A"), .Cells(lr, "A"))
                    .Value = Date
                    .NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yy"
                End With
                .Cells(1, "A").CurrentRegion.offset(1, 0).Copy _
                    Destination:=wb2.Worksheets(i).Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            End With
        Next i
    End With
End Sub

Sub setWbs(ByRef wkbk1 As Workbook, ByRef wkbk2 As Workbook)
    Dim wb As Long

    For wb = 1 To application.Workbooks.Count
        Select Case left(LCase(Workbooks(wb).name), 7)
            Case "source_"
                Set wkbk1 = Workbooks(wb)
            Case "consoli"
                Set wkbk2 = Workbooks(wb)
        End Select
    Next wb
End Sub
```

Comment: I am deleting a line in Consolidated file.( the header of the source which also gets copied). Also, the code is not working for me. It is still unclear to me, if I can give partial name with *, will it work. In your code, I am getting error here : With .Worksheets(i), Object variable or with block variable not set.

Comment: No need to delete what wasn't copied across. See my revision above.

Comment: :Run time error No..91 is still coming in your code at .Worksheets(i).